# Trigger Native UI from Capacitor Plugin.swift

Tags: ios, swift, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

How can I trigger a iOS native UI from plugin.swift in capacitor plugin.

I have below code as per the documentation

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.bridge.viewController.present(ourCustomViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

What's the ourCustomViewController here? Is this object of CustomViewController class? I have my controller which I pasted from another project named ViewController.

When I try let `viewController=ViewController()`, it says can't find module.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode you can get hints on methods signatures just by typing out the method name. From this we can see the `present` method expects a `UIViewController`.

[image]